# Torchlight is missing some textures

Tags: graphics, games

I am using a Radon HD6850 and just bought the indi bundle. Torchlight is missing all face textures (and face textures only). I have had problems with shaders before (graphic would be displayed as black), but what I am seeing now is a simple removal of the texture, I can see through the head. The fps is fine on full graphics so it doesn't seem to be too much of a driver issue (I am using the drivers that came with ubuntu). I downloaded the game through the USC. Has anyone had this issue and managed to fix it?

Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not coming from your computer, everybody playing Torchlight for Linux is experiencing the same bug. The best you can do is wait a few days until a new build is released which will hopefully fix this issue.

You can have more detailed information here : http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=33348&start=40

Comment: Edward Rudd, who has ported Torchlight on Linux has resolved this issue and a patch will be released soon.